# why RedisLockRegistry does not support Transactional?

Tags: spring-integration

spring-boot: 2.4.4
spring-integration-redis: 5.4.5

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
    ......
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
} 

@Autowired
private RedisLockRegistry redisLock;

final Lock lock = redisLock.obtain(lockKey);
boolean lockFlag = lock.tryLock(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

i follow the code to `JedisScriptingCommands`

```
    public <T> T eval(byte[] script, ReturnType returnType, int numKeys, byte[]... keysAndArgs) {

        Assert.notNull(script, "Script must not be null!");

        if (isQueueing() || isPipelined()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        try {
            return (T) new JedisScriptReturnConverter(returnType)
                    .convert(connection.getJedis().eval(script, JedisConverters.toBytes(numKeys), keysAndArgs));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw convertJedisAccessException(ex);
        }
    }
```

in this method, check if in transaction, if true throw UnsupportedOperationException.

i don't understand why does it not support transaction, and if there any way to bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you really have something relevant to Spring Integration in your problem at all. Feels more like a question to Jedis driver.

Consider to use a Lettuce instead: https://lettuce.io/